# useEffect in rendering component in react js

Tags: reactjs

Here is a useEffect which wrote down in App.js and should every time render and show console.log:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("app");
  });
```

And there is a login page with "/" locatio. when validation func return true it will navigate to other page.
but after navigating to other page useEffect in App.js doesn't shows the log.

[image]

[image]

my goal is here: by every navigate I wanna useEffect runs.
can anyone help me?

Comment: It is because it is executing only on mount..use `window.location.path` or `location` instance of react-router  in dependency array of `useEffect` to get executed everytime you navigae to different paths

Comment: Please share more parts of implemented codes to better understanding.

Comment: use useLocation  hook from react-router

Comment: https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/uselocation